# Eclipse Neon startup error on Macbook Pro

Tags: eclipse, startup

[Heres my edited eclipse ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILbtw.png)

So I am a beginner in java and I have installed Java 9.0.1+11 and JDK 9.1.0 and have installed Eclipse Neon 3 EE for java developers package on my macbook pro. Every time I try to run the eclipse it shows the error:

/Users/Myname/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.log.

Comment: Only Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) works with Java 9 without modifications. For earlier releases the eclipse.ini has to be modified.

Comment: How should it be modified? Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Read the answer in the duplicate carefully. The add modules line starts with **two** `-` characters - `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` you only have one. Even when it works you won't get full Java 9 support, you should really move to Oxygen.1a

Comment: Alright, thanks for your tip.